# selenium: how to load a local html file on mac?

Tags: python, selenium

I am learning selenium with chrome on mac.

I've managed to load the google home page with following code.

```
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
driver = webdriver.Chrome(dir_path+'/chromedriver')
driver.set_page_load_timeout('10')
driver.get('http://google.com')
time.sleep(4)
driver.quit()
```

based on that, I am trying to load a local html file with selenium.

```
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
driver = webdriver.Chrome(dir_path+'/chromedriver')
driver.set_page_load_timeout('10')
driver.get('/Users/selenium/test.html')
time.sleep(4)
driver.quit()
```

chrome launched with a weird string.

[image]

and got this error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/pan/selenium.py",
>   line 11, in 
>       driver.get(dir_path+'/game/dino.html')   File "/Users/pan/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 333, in get
>       self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})   File "/Users/pan/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 321, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/Users/pan/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
>   unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot navigate
>   to invalid URL"}   (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)   (Driver
>   info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68
>   (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6
>   x86_64)

what am i missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding `file://` as the protocol to your local file path. So, the code would then read:

```
driver.get('file:///Users/selenium/test.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

As the exception says, The URL you are trying to get is invalid.

Selenium web driver accepts files.

Try the following:

`driver.get('file://Users/selenium/test.html')`